# Ext.ux.grid.GroupSummary.Calculations in grid strange behavior

Tags: javascript, extjs

I use my custom calculation in ExtJs on this way:

```
   Ext.ux.grid.GroupSummary.Calculations['totalTon'] = function(v, record, field)
   {
       return v + (record.get('area') * record.get('yield'));
   };
```

and grid definition contains row with this custom summing

```
...       ,{
            id: 'result_id',
            header: " ",
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'result',            
            width: 100,
            renderer: function (value, style, record, row, col, store, grid) {
              return Ext.util.Format.number(record.get('area') * record.get('yield'), '0.00');
            },  
            summaryType: 'totalTon',
            summaryRenderer: function(v) {
                return  "<div style='font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;'>Total:" + Ext.util.Format.number(v, '0.00') +" [ton] </div>";
            }                   
          },
```

strange thing here is in fact that this sum works only after I change last row in grid before that it doesn't render totalTon, what could be the problem?